# What makes the windows experience index not applicable on battery?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-experience-index

See the title. The powerplan is the same as if were plugged in and graphics card settings are all set to as if it was plugged in. Why does windows say that the windows experience index isnt applicable?

Comment: what is the full error message? Upload the file "C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log", so that we can look what fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Windows might not be aware of any power management settings set in BIOS.  Some BIOSs have power management settings that limit CPU power, frequency, etc... that would affect the score.